# How to use matplotlib to draw a city state in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

How to use matplotlib to draw the following image, hoping that the 3D histogram is at the coordinate intersection?

[image]

I can only do it as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check out how to use `plot_state_city` in the documentation for [the visualization function](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_state_city.html). The example you are showing seems to change the default colors to `color=['blue', 'yellow']` and the title:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_city

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)

state = DensityMatrix.from_instruction(qc)
plot_state_city(state, color=['blue', 'yellow'], title="New State City")
```

[image: plot_state_city(state, color=['blue', 'yellow'], title="New State City")]